# Segmentation fault while accessing the return address from a C function in 64 bit machine

Tags: c, pointers, memory, gcc, segmentation-fault

I have code in C (linux(x86_64)) some like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
   char k[32];
   int v;
}ABC;

ABC states[6] = {0};

ABC* get_abc()
{
   return &states[5];
}
```

while in main():

```
int main()
{
  ABC *p = get_abc();
     .
     .
     .
  printf("%d\n", p->v); 
}
```

I am getting segmentation fault at printf statement while accessing p->v. I tried to debug it from gdb and it says "can not access the memory". One important thing here is that when I compile this code, gcc throws me a warning on **ABC *p = get_abc();** that I am trying to convert pointer from integer. My question here is that I am returning address of structure from get_abc() then why compiler gives me such warning? why compiler considers it as integer? I think I am getting segmentation fault due to this warning as an integer can not hold memory address in x86_64.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are they in separate files? Did you use a header or function declarations?

Comment: FYI: compiles and runs as expected on Windows with VC compiler (assuming all data within same file).

Comment: This: ABC states[] is already a pointer, returning it wouldn't be enough for reference passing?

Comment: @nneonneo yes they are in separate files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the `get_abc` prototype before `main` function. If function prototype is not available before that function call means, compiler will treat that function by default as passing `int` arguments and returning `int`. Here `get_abc` actually returning 8 byte address, but that value has been suppressed to 4 bytes and it is stored in `ABC *p` variable which leads the crash.

```
ABC* get_abc(); 
int main()
{
    ABC *p = get_abc();
}
```

Note : This crash will not occur in 32 bit machine where size of int and size of address is 4 bytes, because suppression will not happen. But that warning will be there.

Comment: yes they are in separate files and get_abc() is not declared anywhere before the use in main(). I'll try to run it after declaring the get_abc() before use.

Comment: "Here get_abc actually returning 8 byte address, but that value has been suppressed to 4 bytes and it stored in ABC *p variable which leads the crash." This is exactly what I was telling to my colleague after watching the warning(though I didnt know why warning is shown) and you have confirmed it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JewelThief ok :) Is it working fine now, after prototype declaration ?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown us all your code, but I can guess with some confidence that the `get_abc()` and `main()` functions are defined in separate source files, and that there's no visible declaration of `get_abc()` visible from the call in `main()`.

You should create a header file that contains a *declaration* of `get_abc()`:

```
ABC *get_abc();
```

and `#include` that header both in the file that defines `get_abc()` and in the one that defines `main()`. (You'll also need header guards.) You'll need to move the definition of the type `ABC` to that header.

Or, as a quick-and-dirty workaround, you can add an explicit declaration before your definition of `main()` -- but that's a rather brittle solution, since it depends on you to get the declaration exactly right.

In the absence of a visible declaration, and undeclared function is assumed to return `int`. The compiler sees your call to `get_abc()`, generates code to call it *as if* it returned an `int`, and implicitly converts that `int` value to a pointer. Hilarity ensues.

Note: There actually is no implicit conversion from `int` to pointer types, apart from the special case of a null pointer constant, but many compilers implement such an implicit conversion for historical reasons. Also, the "implicit `int`" rule was dropped in the 1999 version of the standard, but again, many compilers still implement it for historical reasons. Your compiler should have options to enable better warnings. If you're using gcc, try `gcc -pedantic -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice explanation. I learnt one more thing today. This makes a good day for me.